# How to access a column result in a left join spanning several tables, with the column appearing twice

Tags: mysql

I have a left join on 4 different tables and I am fetching the mysql result. A problem I have is that the same column name appears in 2 of the tables and has different values (the join is not performed on this column name).

So in the row result it appears twice. When I go $my_result_object->'desired_column' it accesses the second value of the column. How do I access the first one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add `ALIAS`

```
SELECT *, table1.ID AS Table1ID,
          table2.ID AS Table2ID, ....
```

Comment: Currently I am doing a select *. The number of columns is large. How can I add what you suggest to the select *?

Answer (score 1):

Use aliases:

```
SELECT mycolumn AS 'column_which_i_need'
```

You cannot directly add alias when using `*`, the only way is either to list all the columns, or attach the needed one at the end:

```
SELECT *, mycolumn AS 'column_which_i_need'
```